# my sql returns only single value

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, winforms

I have

```
staff table
staff_Id
staff_Accesscode values (access123,code123,staff12)....
```

i have done like this for getting all  values in staff_accesscode

```
DataTable dt2 = null;
string sql = @"SELECT staff_AccessCode FROM staff";
dt2 = xxxxxx.GetData(sql, gBaseUrl);
if (dt2 != null && dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   accessname = dt2.Rows[0]["staff_AccessCode"].ToString();
}
```

but the problem is it returns only last value stored in staff_Accesscode, I mean it returns only this value (staff12)

now i want to get the all values stored in staff_Accesscode field and further i want to  check this value with the txtbox.text

Comment: It is only getting one value because you are only accessing one row?

Comment: Do you have control of this data schema? Did you create the relationships and tables?  Are you storing comma delimited values in a field?

Comment: ya but i have  to get all values in staff_Accesscode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the first row (with index 0) only.
You might iterate through the complete result set:

```
for ( int i = 0; dt2 != null && i < dt2.Rows.Count; ++i )
{
    String tmp = dt2.Rows[ i ]["staff_AccessCode"].ToString();
    if ( tmp.Equals( what_ever_variable_or_constant /* e.g., txtbox.Text */ ) )
    {
        accessname = tmp;
        //break; ?
    }
}
```

Comment: That will overwrite `accessname` on each iteration. It will only return the last result from the query. You should either be doing `accessname += dt2...` or create an `accessname` array and add to that on each iteration: `acessname[i] = dt2.Rows...`

Comment: You can believe, I know that. The problem here is not `accessname` but the lack of iteration. However, I edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

You're only accessing the first row in the line `accessname = dt2.Rows[0]...`; you need to loop through all of the available rows in the collection.